# How to call menu function on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In one of my projects I worked on function that should load different containers. This function works after user clicks on each item on the menu. Now I would like to be able to pass an argument in that function on page load and be able to load desired container. Here is example of my function:

```js
$("#main-menu li a").on('click', mainMenu);
function mainMenu(){
    var containerID = $(this).attr('data-container');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('#main-container > div[id="' + containerID + '"]').show();
    $('#main-container > div:not([id="' + containerID + '"])').hide();
}
```

```css
#main-container > div:not([id="container1"]) {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <p class="navbar-text"><b>Main Menu</b></p>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul id="main-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" data-container="container1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-container="container2">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-container="container3">Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-container="container4">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container1" style="background-color:blue">Container 1</div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container2" style="background-color:orange">Container 2</div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container3" style="background-color:black">Container 3</div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container4" style="background-color:green">Container 4</div>
</div>
```

In the example above you can see that my current code always loads Container 1. There might be situation where I would like to load some other container on page load. My question is how to make my function to work on click and on page load, but at the same time to be able to pass an argument in the function and that way load desired container? If anyone can help me with this example please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#main-menu li a").on('click', mainMenu);
  function mainMenu(){
      var containerID = $(this).attr('data-container');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      $('#main-container > div[id="' + containerID + '"]').show();
      $('#main-container > div:not([id="' + containerID + '"])').hide();
  }

  //find the menu
  $('#main-menu')
     //find the nested link that is related to the section you
     //want to show on page load
    .find('a[data-container="container2"]')
    //trigger click so the mainMenu method happens for it
    .trigger('click');  
});
```

```css
#main-container > div:not([id="container1"]) {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <p class="navbar-text"><b>Main Menu</b></p>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul id="main-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" data-container="container1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-container="container2">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-container="container3">Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-container="container4">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container1" style="background-color:blue">Container 1</div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container2" style="background-color:orange">Container 2</div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container3" style="background-color:black">Container 3</div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container4" style="background-color:green">Container 4</div>
</div>
```